# LF line break instead of CR+LF when exporting text files on Windows

Tags: export

I want my program to always save a text file with unix-style `LF` line breaks (even when *Mathematica* runs on Windows). But the way the built-in `Export` command works depends on the operating system.

For example the following code:

```
testFile = "newlinetest.txt";
testStringList = {"abc", "abc"};
Export[testFile, testStringList, "List"];
BinaryReadList[testFile]
```

Linux or Mac OS gives exactly what I want:

> {97, 98, 99, 10, 97, 98, 99}

Windows adds an extra `CR` symbol:

> {97, 98, 99, **13**, 10, 97, 98, 99}

Is there a normal way to save text files with unix-style newline on Windows?

Answer (score 10):

The default when a file stream is opened on Windows is to open it as a Windows text file, which uses CR/LF line terminators.  To open a stream with no Windows text file translations, use `OpenWrite` with the `BinaryFormat->True` option.

You can pass a stream that you opened with `OpenWrite` to `Export` in place of a file name.  Remember to `Close` the stream when you are done writing to it!

(When you pass a file name rather than a stream, Mathematica's I/O functions (like `Export`) will take care of opening and closing the file for you, but you'll have no control over how it's opened.  Since you want control, don't pass a file name.)

```
testFile = "newlinetest.txt";
testStringList = {"abc", "abc"};
testStream = OpenWrite[testFile, BinaryFormat->True];  (* *** open it yourself *** *)
Export[  testStream  , testStringList, "List"];        (* *** pass the stream *** *)
Close[testStream];                                     (* *** close it yourself *** *)
BinaryReadList[testFile]
```

Comment: I get `{97, 98, 99, 13, 10, 97, 98, 99}` from v7 under Windows.

Comment: I get `{97, 98, 99, 10, 97, 98, 99}` from v9, so I guess they fixed something.

Comment: I get `{97, 98, 99, 13, 10, 97, 98, 99}` from v8 under Windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up with using `BinaryWrite` function. It's kind of messy but works.

```
BinaryWrite[testFile, Flatten[Riffle[ToCharacterCode[testStringList], {10}]]];
Close[testFile];
```

In principle there should be some kind of `LineSeparator` option for `Export` but i couldn't find it.

Comment: (+1) perhaps you can turn your code into a custom [ExportConverter](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DevelopingAnExportConverter.html) ?

Comment: +1 As John Fultz commented under my (deleted) answer, now I think binary I/O might be the best choice.