# A bug in converting some Unicode characters into FullForm?

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation, conversion, character-encoding, named-characters

Currently I know only one [well-documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialCharacters-StringsAndCharacters.html#1943280499) way to convert all special characters in an arbitrary string into their `FullForm`:

> In `InputForm`, all special characters are written out fully when using `"PrintableASCII"`.
>
> ```
> ToString["Lamé \[LongRightArrow] \[Alpha]\[Beta]+", InputForm, 
>    CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > "\"Lam\\[EAcute] \\[LongRightArrow] \\[Alpha]\\[Beta]+\""
> > ```

But exhaustive checking reveals that for some characters this produces wrong results:

```
toInputForm[s_String] := 
  StringTake[ToString[s, InputForm, CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"], {2, -2}];
chs = {#, toInputForm[FromCharacterCode[#]]} & /@ Range[128, 65535];
sel = Select[chs, StringLength[#[[2]]] == 1 &];

Grid[Flatten[Transpose /@ Partition[sel, UpTo@11], 1], Frame -> {All, {{True, False}}}, 
 Spacings -> 0.2, FrameStyle -> LightGray]
```

> [image: grid]

The outputted characters correspond to the ASCII set, not to the original Unicode code points:

```
MinMax@ToCharacterCode@StringJoin@sel[[;; , 2]]
```

> ```
> {0, 127}
> ```

Is there a fix for this? Or is there a robust and efficient way to convert all the special and Unicode characters into their corresponding `FullForm`s?

---

P.S. An attempt to start from `FullForm` also produces wrong result:

```
ToString[FullForm@StringJoin@sel[[;; , 2]], OutputForm]
```

> ```
> "\"\\000\\001\\002\\003\\004\\005\\006\\007\\b\\t\\013\\f\\016\\017\\020\\021\\022\\023\\\
> 024\\025\\026\\027\\030\\031\\032\\[RawEscape]\\034\\035\\036\\037\\177\""
> ```

`Export`ing as `"Package"` produces the correct output but it contains ugly header and several redundant newlines:

```
ExportString[FromCharacterCode[Range[61952, 61983]~Join~{62079}], "Package", 
 PageWidth -> Infinity]
```

> ```
> "(* Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com *)
>
> \"\\:f200\\:f201\\:f202\\:f203\\:f204\\:f205\\:f206\\:f207\\:f208\\:f209\\:f20a\\:f20b\\:\
> f20c\\:f20d\\:f20e\\:f20f\\:f210\\:f211\\:f212\\:f213\\:f214\\:f215\\:f216\\:f217\\:f218\\\
> :f219\\:f21a\\:f21b\\:f21c\\:f21d\\:f21e\\:f21f\\:f27f\"
>
> "
> ```

I'm hoping for something more elegant than cleaning out this...

Answer (score 5):

I've contacted the support on this issue ([CASE:3933761]) but received nothing better than a suggestion to manually clean up the `"Package"` string using `StringDrop`. The following is my attempt to develop a workaround based on the `"Package"` export.

First, we can remove the package header by adding `"Comments" -> None`:

```
string = FromCharacterCode[Range[61952, 61983]];
p = ExportString[string, "Package", PageWidth -> Infinity, "Comments" -> None]
```

> ```
> "\"\\:f200\\:f201\\:f202\\:f203\\:f204\\:f205\\:f206\\:f207\\:f208\\:f209\\:f20a\\:f20b\\:\
> f20c\\:f20d\\:f20e\\:f20f\\:f210\\:f211\\:f212\\:f213\\:f214\\:f215\\:f216\\:f217\\:f218\\\
> :f219\\:f21a\\:f21b\\:f21c\\:f21d\\:f21e\\:f21f\"\r\n"
> ```

Tracing `ExportString` and experimenting shows that basically it is equivalent to the following:

```
Module[{stream = Developer`StreamToString[CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII",
    FormatType -> InputForm, BinaryFormat -> True], result},
 Write[stream, string];
 result = Developer`StringFromStream@stream;
 Close[stream];
 result]
```

(here `BinaryFormat -> True` is added mostly due to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18354/280) feature).

It is important that unlike `ExportString` this method produces under Windows a string ending with `\"\n`, not with `\"\r\n` what simplifies further clean-up.

**The main problem with this method is that it leaves the ASCII characters untouched, so the control ASCII characters won't be converted into their printable representation.**

But it does work correctly for all non-ASCII characters:

```
inputForm[string_String] := 
 Module[{stream = Developer`StreamToString[CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII", 
     FormatType -> InputForm, BinaryFormat -> True], result},
  Write[stream, string];
  result = StringDrop[Developer`StringFromStream@stream, -1];
  Close[stream];
  result]

check = With[{if = inputForm[#]}, ToExpression[if] === # && StringLength[if] > 3] & /@ 
  FromCharacterCode /@ Range[128, 65535];

And @@ check
```

> ```
> True
> ```

(checked with *Mathematica* 10.4.1 and 11.1.1; this code crashes Kernel of version 8.0.4).

The `CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"` option value is supported by `` Developer`StreamToString `` but it contains exactly the same bug as the documented method shown in the question.

The above partial solution is equivalent to documented and more stable `ToString` method which should be preferred:

```
inputForm[s_String] := ToString[s, InputForm, CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"];
```

The non-printable ASCII characters can be manually replaced with their `FullForm`s using `StringReplace`.