# Explicitly control newline behaviour when writing strings with arbitary encoding

Tags: export, string-manipulation, character-encoding, streams

On Windows system, *Mathematica* by default opens stream which will automatically transform any `"\n"` into `"\r\n"`. But I want pure line feed. In this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18354/4742), librik suggested using `BinaryFormat->True` in `OpenWrite` to explicitly control newline behaviour.

In this way,

```
tmp = OpenWrite[file, BinaryFormat -> True];
WriteString[tmp, "test", "\n", "test"];
Close[tmp]
```

will give correctly

[image]

in which, "LF" is line feed corresponding to `"\n"` or 10th ASCII character.

However, if I want write Chinese characters, this is not working. For example

```
tmp = OpenWrite[file, BinaryFormat -> True, 
   CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
WriteString[tmp, "测试", "\n", "test"];
Close[tmp]
```

Even though, I set `CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"`, the result is

[image]

The words are gone!

So librik's solution needs some extension. How to control newline for outputing any string?

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is it seems when you open `BinaryFormat->True` it ignores the `CharacterEncoding` directive.  This is a hack writing to a ascii scratch file to extract the utf8 binary encoding:

```
tobytes[c_String] := Module[
  {b, tmp, scratch = "scratch.file"},
  tmp = OpenWrite[scratch, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
  WriteString[tmp, c]; Close[tmp];
  tmp = OpenRead[scratch, BinaryFormat -> True];
  b = BinaryReadList[tmp, "Byte"]; Close[tmp];
  b]

f = OpenWrite["out.txt", BinaryFormat -> True]
BinaryWrite[f, tobytes["测试"]]
BinaryWrite[f, "\ntext\n"]
Close[f]
```

Checking output:

```
f = OpenRead["out.txt", BinaryFormat -> True]
Flatten@ToCharacterCode[BinaryReadList[f, "Character8"]]
Close[f]
```

> {230, 181, 139, 232, 175, 149, 10, 116, 101, 120, 116, 10}

compare basic non binary `WriteString` (on windows)

```
f = OpenWrite["out.txt", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
WriteString[f, "测试\ntext\n"]
Close[f]
f = OpenRead["out.txt", BinaryFormat -> True]
Flatten@ToCharacterCode[BinaryReadList[f, "Character8"]]
Close[f]
```

> {230, 181, 139, 232, 175, 149, 13, 10, 116, 101, 120, 116, 13, 10}

you see its the same except dropping the "13" ascii CR.

Comment: Thank you so much george2079. +1

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to george2079. Inspired by george2079's use of `BinaryWrite` and `ToCharacterCode`. I found the whole thing can be as simple as

```
file = "R:\\test.txt";
BinaryWrite[file, ToCharacterCode["测试\ntest", "UTF-8"]];
Close[file]
```

I found learning some essential character encoding is important for understanding the low level stuff. I recommend [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

In Short, what happens here is that `unicode` maps all characters which exists on earth into unique numbers(called code point). `UTF-8` is an 8-bit(one byte) encoding scheme to encode these unique numbers. `ToCharacterCode` transforms any string into `UTF-8` encoding and results in a list of integers ranges from 0 to 255(one byte range), `BinaryWrite` write these integers byte by byte into file. Finally, if you open the file with `UTF-8` encoding, you see the right content.